# What is the way to encode json template to html with angularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I'm a beginner in AngularJS and I try to render a json in html with angularJS but html tags are not encoded. Is there a way to do that with an angularJS method ?

My HTML:

```
<p>{{template.title}}</p>
```

My JSON:

```
{
    "title":"try a <br> to break line"
}
```

My JS:

```
$http.get(JSON).success(function (data) {
        $scope.template = data;
});
```

Unfortunately, the render display the br tag

Comment: What version of AngularJS are you using?  It is important as 1.2+ differs from <1.2

Comment: I use the 1.0.7 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular wants to bind text as text by default.

In Angular <1.2.0 you need to bind the html unsafe (this can be dangerous):

```
<h1 ng-bind-html-unsafe="title"></h1>
```

In Angular 1.2.0 you need to bind the html:

```
<h1 ng-bind-html="title"></h1>
```

Dont forget to include ngSanitize to keep your server safe.

Overall, I recommend using Angular 1.2.0 rc2 or later versions as the ngSanitize will keep you safe.

Comment: I use 1.0.7 version, with ng-bind-html-unsafe, it seems to work but my content appears empty now :-(

Comment: Make sure that you are binding the right scope variable. I just used what I thought your's might be in my example.

Comment: You're right. I used ng-bind-html-unsafe="title". But it works fine with ng-bind-html-unsafe="template.title", thank you very much guy. Now I have to see how ngSanitize works. thx!

Comment: ngSanitize is new in Angular 1.2.0. Like I said, if you can get by using it until they release it stable, its a nice upgrade over the 1.0 feature set.

Comment: Thank you, I hope to can do the upgrade to developp when everything  will be stable in my web-app at the current time.